# R selenium - Fix the eror

Tags: r, rselenium

I try to run RSelenium:

```
library(RSelenium)
rs_driver_object <-  rsDriver(browser = 'firefox',
                               chromever = '105.0.1',
                               verbose = F,
                               port = free_port())
```

I am facing an error after running:

```
Error in open. Connection(con, "rb") : Failed to connect to www.googleapis.com port 443: Timed out"
```

I don't know how to fix this problem. Please help me.
Thank you

Comment: Do you need to use `chromever` when you are using Firefox? And have you loaded the `netstat` package?

Answer (score 0):

You can consider the following approach (note : you need to install docker to make this work (see https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/)) :

```
library(RSelenium)
shell('docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox')
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4445L, browserName = "firefox")
```